# Navigate from a stack to another in react native navigation

Tags: react-native-navigation

I have two stacks ( Home and Settings ) in the bottom tab bar, how to navigate using REACT NATIVE NAVIGATION from Home to Settings passing a props?

Answer (score 1):

Each of the screen gets 'navigation' as a prop. You can call navigation.navigate("<SCREEN_NAME>") to move to other screen.